# Splitting with pipe and additional spaces around this symbol if any using separate in R

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

How to separate a column into many, based on a symbol "|" and  any additional spaces around this symbol if any:

```
 input <- tibble(A = c("Ae1 tt1 | Ae2 tt2", "Be1 | Be2 | Be3")) 

 output <-  tibble(B = c("Ae1 tt1", "Be1") , C = c("Ae2 tt2", "Be2"), D = c(NA, "Be3"))
```

I tried :

```
 input %>% 
    separate(A, c("B","C","D"))
    #separate(A, c("B","C","D"), sep = "|.")
    #mutate(B = str_split(A, "*|")) %>% unnest
```

What is the syntax with regex ?

Solution from [R - separate with specific symbol, vertical bare, |](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56047726/11329890) (and [tidyr::separate() producing unexpected results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55481521/11329890)) does not provide expected output and produces a warning:

```
input %>% separate(col=A, into=c("B","C","D"), sep = '\\|')
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  B          C          D     
  <chr>      <chr>      <chr> 
1 "Ae1 tt1 " " Ae2 tt2"  <NA> 
2 "Be1 "     " Be2 "    " Be3"
Warning message:
Expected 3 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 1 rows [1].
```

[Using separate from tidyr with different length vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26804641/11329890) does not  seem related unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
output <- input %>%
    separate(col=A, into=c("B","C","D"), sep="\\s*\\|\\s*", fill="right")
```

R test:

```r
> input %>% separate(col=A, into=c("B","C","D"), sep="\\s*\\|\\s*", fill="right")
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  B       C       D    
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
1 Ae1 tt1 Ae2 tt2 <NA> 
2 Be1     Be2     Be3
```

The `\s*\|\s*` pattern matches a pipe char with any zero or more whitespace chars on both ends of the pipe.

The `fill="right"` argument fills with missing values on the right.